# Problem in interpreting Rewriterule parameters in htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a site in Serbian and English.
URL-friendly link determine which language will be displayed. The language specifies the first parameter after the domain name (/sr/ or /en/).
For text in serbian language, this is a link:

`www.mysite.com/sr/proizvodi/product-name/25`

and for english, this is a link:

`www.mysite.com/en/products/product-name/25`

My .htaccess file has commands:

`RewriteRule ^sr/proizvodi/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ details.php?id=$2&lang=sr [L]`

`RewriteRule ^en/products/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ details.php?id=$2&lang=en [L]`

The problem is that the site launches the English version if pattern "en" also appears in the product name. For exampl:

[www.mysite.com/sr/proizvodi/vis**en**am**en**ska](http://www.mysite.com/sr/proizvodi/vis**en**am**en**ska) cetka/129

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please provide that last URL without the `*` characters?

Comment: I think you need to add the `NE` (no escape) flag to prevent the `&` in your target URLs becoming `%26`. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne